# GeoServer Heatmap WMS style problem

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, sld

I just try to visualize some points using GeoServer to publish them as WMS and bind this WMS to my Openlayers website using the GeoServer internal Heatmap process to visualize it. I don't want to use the Openlayers Heatmap function.

But there seem to be some problems, look here:

[image]

I'm using this Openlayers implementation to bind my WMS URL:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html

Changing the params to:

```
params: {'LAYERS': 'test:points','TILED': true,'STYLES': 'heatmap'},
```

And using this as SLD to define the Heatmap:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Hello Andrej.

I have the same problem with that. I wonder, finally have you resolved this question??
On my case, I have been using Mapbox to take a WMS published in Geoserver and the tiles are not draw correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a **tiled** WMS request each request is a completely separate request, GeoServer has no idea of the others (in fact with a load balancer they could go to different machines). So when you ask for a tiled heat map it takes just the points in the area of the tile and makes a heat map of them. Obviously this doesn't work.

TL;DR; Solution: don't use tiles for heatmaps.

Comment: While it is possible to load single tiles with Openlayers, by default this is not possible using Leaflet. But I found an implementation to do this: https://github.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer . Just in case somebody needs to know. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass Date.now() as a WMS parameter, you can avoid this as none of the tiles will be cached - it will generate a new tile request every time.

Example below is for Leaflet - i'm not sure if it can be done in Openlayers.

```
var wms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://server:8080/geoserver/wms", 
{
    layers: layer,
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    no_cache_plz: Date.now()

}).addTo(map);
```